# Android and iPhone drag (touchmove,sweep)

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ios, mobile

I'm developing HTML5 app for Android and iOS. All I need is to slide hidden menu by sweeping it right and hiding it back with a left sweep.

I can use CSS3 transition for the animation so what I'm looking for is really simple framework which provides the javascript events or if someone has experience.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with jQuery in any sense, then [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) would be good enough (and light-weighted) to get your problem solved.

Comment: Yeah, I've searched and chose this one. Now when there's a match with  your recommendation I'm even more confident with my choice.
10x